# Not receiving correct value from Config file in Selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Have data in  config file as 
`test_data_path = C:\\Sudheer\\Sudheer\\Selinium scripts\\Webdriverscrip\\Automation_Project\\TestData\\Nlpapplication.xlsx`

when I run my below script result is shown with one Slash missing

`C:\Sudheer\Sudheer\Selinium scripts\Webdriverscrip\Automation_Project\TestData\Nlpapplication.xlsx`

```
public class Testconfigvalues  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fs = null;
        fs = new  FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\config.properties");
        Properties property=new Properties();
        property.load(fs);
        String data_test_data_path = property.getProperty("test_data_path");
        System.out.println("value is " +data_test_data_path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override function load function as it is escaping \ character.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Properties;

public class NetbeansProperties extends Properties {

@Override
public synchronized void load(Reader reader) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(reader);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    String readLine = null;
    while ((readLine = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
        out.write(readLine.replace("\\", "\\\\").getBytes());
        out.write("\n".getBytes());
    } 

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    super.load(is);
  }

   @Override
   public void load(InputStream is) throws IOException {
       load(new InputStreamReader(is));
    }   
}
```

Class to read data from config file:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fs = null;
        fs = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\config.properties");
        NetbeansProperties property = new NetbeansProperties();
        property.load(fs);
        String data_test_data_path = property.getProperty("test_data_path");
        System.out.println("value is " + data_test_data_path);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, just saw your post , will try and let you know

Comment: And also i found another method by using TESTNG where i given the path directly in Testng.xml file which has called the parameters.  This helps my code to be reusable to my team as they can give path in xml file rather than in code <suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Nopackage" >
  <parameter name="Testdatapath" value="C:\\Sudheer\\Sudheer\\NBC\\Selinium scripts\\Webdriverscrip\\NLPAutomation_Project\\TestData\\Nlpapplication.xlsx"/>
  <parameter name="ObjectidDocPath" value="C:\\Sudheer\\Sudheer\\NBC\\Selinium scripts\\Webdriverscrip\\NLPAutomation_Project\\jectids.xlsx"/>